# How can I get the progress of an FTP Download in WinInet C++

Tags: c++, ftp, wininet

I'm creating a program which downloads a file from an FTP server. I want to display the progress of how much bytes the user has downloaded. I have tried searching for it but I couldn't find anything. First , my plan was to get the file size using fstream but then I realized that I can't share 2 processes at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using [`FtpGetFile(..)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384157%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to download the file from the FTP server. This is the simple way of downloading a file which gives you no information about how many bytes are already downloaded and you have very little control how the function behaves (e.g. cancelling of a download upon user request?). For quick test it is very helpful, though.

In order to monitor the download progress do the following:

1. Determine size of remote file using `FtpFindFirstFile`.
2. Open remote file using `FtpOpenFile`.
3. Create local file using `CreateFile`.
4. Read some bytes from remote file using `InternetReadFile`.
5. Evaluate return value and error code of `InternetReadFile` the detect errors and if transmittion is complete.
6. Write these bytes to local file using `WriteFile`.
7. Calculate/Update your progress information.
8. Go back to step 4 if file is not downloaded entirely and there is no error.
9. Close local file using `CloseHandle`.
10. Close remote file using `InternetCloseHandle`.

If you need more help I can offer some code doing this...